# How to get the attribute value of xml using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml schema.

```
<Rooms>
    <Room RoomNumber="room1" EMAIL="ssds@dsfd.com" dsfdd=""/>
    <Room RoomNumber="room2" EMAIL="ssds@sdd.com" dsfdd=""/>
</Rooms>
```

I have to return Email address based on the input(input to program is room number).

How i can achieve this using LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(myXmlFilePath);
// or doc = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString);

string roomNumber = "room1";

var emailQuery = from room in doc.Root.Elements("Room")
                 where (string)room.Attribute("RoomNumber") == roomNumber
                 select (string)room.Attribute("EMAIL");
```

Then, with a query like that you can get results:

```
// if there is always only one <Room> with given roomNumber
var email = emailQuery.First();
// otherwise
var emails = emailQuery.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<Rooms>"+
                "<Room RoomNumber=\"room1\" EMAIL=\"ssds@dsfd.com\" dsfdd=\"\"/>"+
        "<Room RoomNumber=\"room2\" EMAIL=\"ssds@sdd.com\" dsfdd=\"\"/>"+
                 "</Rooms>");

string room = "room1"; //input
var email =   xml.Elements("Room")
                        .Where(c => c.Attribute("RoomNumber").Value == room)
                        .Select(c => c.Attribute("EMAIL").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It won't work. My question is if i give input as "room1" i have to get ssds@dsfd.com and if i/p is "room2" then o/p should be "ssds@sdd.com". Thanks in advance