# Read Attributes from XML Web Response in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, response

I've been searching, but can't really find an answer.

I'm working on my own Movie Collection software, where I'm using the OMDBApi (http://omdbapi.com/) and I want to implement a search function.
OMDB's Response is a XML string:

```
<root response="True">
    <Movie Title="Pain &amp; Gain" Year="2013" imdbID="tt1980209" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="No Pain, No Gain" Year="2005" imdbID="tt0306846" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="Chris Rock: Bring the Pain" Year="1996" imdbID="tt0200529" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="Confession of Pain" Year="2006" imdbID="tt0834902" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="Laugh at My Pain" Year="2011" imdbID="tt1999192" Type="movie"/>
    ...
</root>
```

I've tried with XElement.Parse etc, but I can't find a way to get the attributes.

XML has never been my strongest side, it wouldn't be a problem if the response string was in different nodes like `<Title></title> <Year></Year>`. But to get attributes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267530/how-to-get-the-attribute-value-of-xml-using-linq-to-xml)

**LINQ to XML** technology very useful to work with XML Data.